# Foreign keys in fixtures in rails 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I'm having problems with my fixtures in Rails.

I have two models, a message and a user. The user model is generated from restful authentication. A message has a sender and a recipient, which are both users.

When I don't use the fixtures everything works fine. But when I try to use them in fixtures both are nil.

This is the messages fixtures file:

```
first_message_for_quentin:
    title: First message
    body: This is your first message.
    recipient: quentin
    sender: aaron
```

quentin and aaron are the user fixtures which were generated by restful authentication.

Is there a way I can use the generated ids there or do I have to do it another way?

Comment: Have you looked into factory_girl, Machinist or fixjour as fixtures replacements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fixture file which was created by restful authentication.

```
quentin:
    id: 1
    ...

aaron:
    id: 2
    ...
```

I removed these ids and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The ActiveRecord Fixtures creates the ID column for each row by calling `Fixtures.identify` on the label you gave the row in the yaml.

So you should be able to do something like the following:

```
first_message_for_quentin:
    title: First message
    body: This is your first message.
    recipient_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:quentin) %>
    sender_id: <%= Fixtures.identify(:aaron) %>
```

You might want to look at some of the [docs](http://rails.noobkit.com/show/ruby/rails/rails-edge/activerecord/fixtures.html#toc-fixture-label-interpolation) for fixture label interpolation.

Comment: This didn't work. I dug somewhat deeper and found the real problem.